# Ember.js testing: follow <a> link

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I'm testing an Ember app and I've got a link inside a table.

I can get to the link by the selector:

```
$('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a')
```

In my test I have:

```
click($('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a'));
```

But after doing `console.log(currentURL());` I am not on the link that the above click should have taken me to.

Do I need to be more specific with the link to click? Or am I using click wrong? Or is there a different test helper I should be using?

Comment: I did not. I did something else to solve the problem, but can't remember what now.

Answer (score 0):

click is an asynchronous method, you need to wait for it to complete before attempting to view the results.

```
click($('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a'));
andThen(function(){
  console.log(currentURL());
});
```

or

```
click($('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a')).then(function(){
  console.log(currentURL());
});
```

Comment: I've tried the first suggestion, and just tried it again and the same thing happens. It doesn't go to the URL in the link.

The second doesn't return anything and the console.log is never triggered. I put it in an alert and that didn't activate either. The test says Object not found.

Comment: Is it outside of your ember app?

Comment: It's in my testing suite along with my other tests.

Comment: I mean the anchor tag, is it part of a template inside of the app.

Comment: Yes. I can put in $('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) a') in the dev console and it will highlight the link on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this exact problem.  In the Ember app, I can click on the  tag and a modal dialog pops up, as expected.  In the test I'm writing for this modal, nothing seems to work.  I can type

```
Ember.$('#id-of-tag').click();
```

on the JS console, and the modal appears.  I paste that into the test and nothing happens. 
I've tried click(find('#id-of-tag')[0]) too.

We're using Ember 2.7.3 but will switch to 2.12 very soon.